# Cannot install newer version of FreeCAD from PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, cad

I'm trying to install FreeCAD on my computer (running 18.10), and am running into a bit of trouble with the installation. I would like to use the latest stable release from `ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable`, as the version in the main repositories is outdated and has several errors on startup. The issue is, even after adding the PPA to my sources, `apt` still installs the version from the official repositories.

This is my output from running `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                     
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-5/ubuntu cosmic InRelease      
Fetched 241 kB in 1s (343 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

So you would think the latest packages from the FreeCAD maintainers stable PPA should be available, right? However, the output of `apt policy freecad` is

```
freecad:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.16.6712+dfsg1-3build1
  Version table:
     0.16.6712+dfsg1-3build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
```

If it's useful, here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.10 _Cosmic Cuttlefish_ - Release amd64 (20181017.3)]/ cosmic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic contrib
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic contrib
```

And here's the output of `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:03 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  5 11:02 elmer-csc-ubuntu-ubuntu-elmer-csc-ppa-cosmic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  5 11:02 elmer-csc-ubuntu-ubuntu-elmer-csc-ppa-cosmic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  172 Dec  5 11:02 freecad-maintainers-ubuntu-freecad-stable-cosmic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  172 Dec  5 11:02 freecad-maintainers-ubuntu-freecad-stable-cosmic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140 Dec  5 11:02 js-reynaud-ubuntu-kicad-5-cosmic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140 Dec  5 11:02 js-reynaud-ubuntu-kicad-5-cosmic.list.save
```

If there's anything that might be useful that I forgot to provide, please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @CharlesGreen According to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), Cosmic was releasted October 18, 2018. Edit: formatting

Comment: I'm getting behind myself again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not blindly add PPAs to the system.

Check two things:

1. package versions in the standard repositories - using search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=freecad&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=cosmic&section=all):

   > **Package freecad**
   >
   > cosmic (18.10) (science): Extensible Open Source CAx program [**universe**]
   >      0.16.6712+dfsg1-3build1: amd64 arm64 i386 ppc64el s390x
2. package versions on PPA's page on LaunchPad (for [`ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable` and *cosmic* release](https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-stable?field.series_filter=cosmic)):

   > **Package**    **Version**                                                **Uploaded by**
   >   freecad      1:0.17.13541-1ppa3~ubuntu18.10.1    Kurt Kremitzki (2018-12-11)

So the package should be updated automatically after:

1. adding PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable
   ```

   (in command above `sudo apt update` is automatic) then
2. upgrading packages

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```

   to get new dependencies.

---

But in this particular case you can see that the build for *cosmic* [was not successful](https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-stable/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=cosmic):

> [image: FreeCAD build failed]

so this PPA do not have deb-files named `freecad_0.17.13541-1ppa3~ubuntu18.10.1*.deb` in the [`pool` directory](http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freecad/?C=S;O=A).

You may consider to:

- ask PPA owner to get successful build for Ubuntu 18.10.
- get newest Daily build of FreeCAD from corresponding PPA named  [`ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily`](https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-daily?field.series_filter=cosmic) as its latest build [was successful](https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-daily/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=cosmic).

Answer (score 0):

I had Freecad 0.18 running on my ubuntu 18.10, but the last week it broke. Ubuntu has updated some packages in python. We have to notify the freecad developers for that i guess its an easy fix

Comment: today it finally starts, but not everything works :( However the appimage from their website works perfect